# jquery slideToggle prolem with image

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using jQuery slideToggle() on div wrapper. All works fine until I put bigger image inside.
let's say the wrapper is 300px wide and the image inside is 1000 x 500 px and is set to have width 100%. So the image automaticly is scaled down to 300px by 150px. The problem is when the wrapper is toggled visible it stretches to 500px and when the animation is finished it jumps back to 150px.
Is there way how to avoid this?

the code is something like this

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="image-wrapper">
   <img src"..." width="100%" />
 </div>
</div>

#wrapper{
 width: 30%;
}
```

Comment: have you tried `width: 300px !important;`?

Comment: I cant do that, width depends on screen size, so it just has to fill the wrapper, which does. The problem is height of the image during animation.

Comment: ah i thought the width is the problem.

Comment: i tried it on jsfiddle and i don't seem to get that problem: http://jsfiddle.net/dKSQ6/ could you maybe link to your page or some more code?

Comment: tried at my local environment and also do not see any problem. Try to provide some example with your issue

Comment: thanks guys, but that is not the case here. in your fiddle the wrapper has FIXED height and width. None of it I can have in my code. The width is determined by screen size and height should be just proportional to width.